# How do I completely uninstall Android?

Tags: windows-7, eclipse, uninstall

I'm trying to Install Android SDK with Eclipse on my computer. I did something wrong (I think I installed some Galileo components into Juno) and the Android plugins aren't working correctly. 
When I deleted Eclipse directly and pulled it out of the .zip again, the plugins were all still installed. Does anyone know where they are, so I can delete them?

Comment: You need to specify whether you're running Windows, Mac OS X or Linux.

Comment: @Michael O yes- Windows 7, 64-bit.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/17625622/632951 , though that is asking for Android **Studio**.

Comment: Install Plug-in Development Environment (PDE) then the [Plugin Registry](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/guide/tools/views/plugin_registry.htm?cp=4_3_8_0) will tell you where your plugins are.

Answer (score 1):

If you are still trying out and not into serious development, go with android Studio. Its much more tailored for android development and is the one which has more active development going forward.

If you want to continue using eclipse, plugins are installed under plugins folder at eclipse installation.

Comment: I don't even remember what computer this question was for anymore. :P

IntelliJ really does make great IDEs.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, Eclipse plugins are stored in the `plugins` folder underneath the main Eclipse folder (which is wherever you put it).

Comment: It still is showing everything as installed.

Comment: Is there anywhere else that it keeps data?